# compare values of two pair of RDDs based on key in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

Is there a way to compare values of 2 pair `RDDs` based on key.
For example:

```
RDD1: RDD[(Int, String)] = {(1, "ABC"), (2, "XYZ"), (3, "PQR")}
RDD2: RDD[(Int, String)] = {(5, "AAA"), (2, "XYZ"), (3, "LMN")}
```

My task is to get the number of keys present in both `rdds` where values are different.
The join gives `rdd` with keys `2` and `3`.
But i want final output as `3` **Because the values are different**.

I've tried the below approach:

```
var diff = rdd1.join(rdd2).map{case(k,(s1,s2))=> if (s1!=s2) (k,s1)}
```

So I can get count of diff. But it gives both keys `2` and `3`. I guess I need else condition to skip the matching value.
Can anyone please suggest how I can achieve desired result? (or using any different approach).

Answer (score 2):

Use `collect`, which takes a *partial function* and removes values for which that partial function isn't defined. Then, include the "if" as a *guard* in the case statement, instead of part of the case result expression:

```
val diff = rdd1.join(rdd2).collect {
  case (k, (s1, s2)) if s1 != s2 => (k, s1)
}
```

This way, the partial function won't be defined where `s1 == s2`, which would make `collect` filter them out.

An equivalent (but slightly less elegant) solution would use `map` and `filter` - `map` alone would always return the same number of records as the input:

```
val diff = rdd1.join(rdd2).filter {
  case (k, (s1, s2)) => s1 != s2
}.map {
  case (k, (s1, s2)) => (k, s1)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `leftInnerJoin` to where key present in first rdd and count on it.

```
val diff = rdd1.leftOuterJoin(rdd2).count()
```